# Find two points $B$ and $C$, each inscribed in a different circumference such that the intersection of the circles is their midpoint

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am getting started on problem solving, and, embarrassingly enough, couldn't do the first geometry exercise of "Solving mathematical problems, a personal perspective". The full question is as follows:

"Let k and l be two circles that intersect in two points P and Q. Construct the line m through P, not containing Q, with the property that if m intersects k in B and P, and m intersects l in C and P, then |PB| = |PC|; see figure below. (Hint: solve for B.)"

[image]

Comment: Where is the figure?

Comment: Also, pls share the details of your attempt to solve it

Comment: You uploaded no figure... Please refer to this link https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: sorry, will fix

Comment: @MathLover All I have been able to do is label each circle's center, $X$ for $k$ and $Y$ for $l$, and creating the 2 isosceles triangles $CXP$ and $PYD$, along with $XPY$. I named angles $\angle{PXY}$ and $\angle{XYP}$ $\angle\alpha$ and $\angle\beta$ respectively. I know that if I could express angle $\angle{XPC}$ in terms of $\angle\alpha$ and $\angle\beta$ the problem would be solved, but I haven't been able too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind this solution: Consider an arbitrary point $X$. Then there is exactly one point $Y$ such that $P$ is the midpoint of segment $XY$. The transformation of the plane from $X$ to $Y$ for all these points $X$ is just a 180 degree rotation centered around point $P$. So we're looking for a point on one circle whose opposite point by this transformation is on the other circle. We can find this by drawing the image of one circle after this transformation.

So, let $K$ be the center of circle $k$ and $L$ the center of circle $l$. To transform $l$, draw line $PL$, and find $L'$ on the line with $LP=PL'$. Draw the circle $l'$ centered at $L'$ through $P$. Then circle $l'$ intersects circle $k$ at points $P$ and $B$.

Comment: Ingenius solution, its so obvious on hindsight, but I guess all geometry problems are.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be the centers of circles $k$ and $l$, and let $M$ and $N$ be the midpoints of $BP$ and $PC$ respectively. Construct the line parallel to $XM$ and $YN$ passing through point $P$, and let $R$ be its intersection with $XY$. By Thales Theorem we have $XR \cong RY$. Note that since $XM \perp BC$ and $YN\perp BC$, we also have $PR \perp BC$.

Thus you can determine the line $m$ as the line perpendicular to the line connecting $P$ with the midpoint of segment $XY$.

[image]

Comment: I'm really new to this stuff, so I'll ask a bunch of questions which will seem silly to you. Why are $YN$ and $XM$ parallel to each other? And why are they perpendicular to $BC$?

Comment: @DollarStoreRichard don't worry about asking quesitons! In genera the line connecting the midpoint of a chord  and the circle center is perpendicular to the chord (in order to show that, just consider, e.g. the isosceles triangle $\triangle XPB$ and note that $\triangle XPM \cong\triangle  XPM$ by SSS criterion). $XM$ and $YN$ are parallel to each other because they are both perpendicular to $BC$. Hope this clarifies a little.